# What is the name of Germanic n > m near f / Greek ν > μ near π transformation?

Tags: greek, germanic-languages

What is the name of  Germanic n > m near f / Greek ν > μ near π transformation?

Comment: It's just assimilation. The nasal acquires the labial characteristic of the stop.

Comment: More specifically, nasal place assimilation.

Comment: I'm not sure why someone VTC'd as opinion-based; whether or not this is a good question, "assimilation" is standard terminology.

Comment: @Draconis indeed, it's neither opinion-based nor does it need details or clarity. It might not be a great question, but it has a very direct and definite answer. Given I don't know all that much about linguistics, I spend most of my time here voting on question closures, and I am often quite appalled by what I see.

Answer (score 7):

This is **assimilation of place**, where one sound changes its place of articulation to match an adjacent sound. It's very common cross-linguistically, e.g. Latin *in-* + *par* > *i**m**par* "unequal", or Swahili *ny-* + *-bwa* > ***m**bwa* "dog".